# php json парсинг внутри (callback)

Tags: php

Здравствуйте! Подскажите пожалуйста, как мне спарсить значения json файла, который обернут в callback ?

Получаю значение так:

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/00.000.00.00');
$data = json_decode($json);
```

Само получаемое значение:

```
callback({"country_code":"RU","country_name":"COUNTRY","city":"CITY","postal":null,"latitude":00.0000,"longitude":00.0000,"IPv4":"00.000.00.00","state":" REGION'"})
```

Нужны только country_name, city, state

Comment: кажется здесь только остается регуляркой удалить название функции и скобки, а потом уже передать в json_decode то что осталось

Comment: я пыталась, но не понимаю как это сделать

Comment: и нет ли другого варианта?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для одного уровня вложенности можно так.

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://geoip-db.com/jsonp/00.000.00.00');
preg_match_all("/\{.*\}/",$json,$data2);
$data = json_decode($data2[0][0]);
echo $data->IPv4;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, это помогло!

Answer (score 1):

Можно вырезать вызов с помощью регулярного выражения `/^\w+\((.*)\)$/`
Мы просто пропускаем идентификатор(имя функции) и скобки и захватываем всё, что осталось(искомый json).

*Приведённый в вопросе JSON невалиден, 00.00000 - не является валидным числом*

[Fiddle](https://3v4l.org/CXnLc)

```
<?php

$json = 'callback({"country_code":"RU","country_name":"COUNTRY","city":"CITY","postal":null,"latitude":0.0000,"longitude":0.0000,"IPv4":"00.000.00.00","state":" REGION\'"})';
preg_match('/^\w+\((.*)\)$/', $json, $match);
if (!$match) die('Malformed JSONP');

$data = json_decode($match[1], true);
if (!$data) die ('Malformed JSON');
var_dump($data);
```

В случае, если исходный JSON может быть многострочным, нужно модифицировать регулярное выражение для захвата любых символов(включая переносы строки).

Например, так:

```
'/^\w+\(([\s\S]*)\)$/m'
```

Comment: 0000  это я написала за место айпишника или других чисел. разумеется значения будут иными

Comment: я про `"latitude":00.0000` в теле json в вопросе